# "non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation" when generating signature of an image in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, plsql

After creating a directory for media elements in "c:\work"
I declared the directory in sqlplus

```
> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY FILE_DIR as 'c:\work'; 
> GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY FILE_DIR TO anonymous;
```

I created a type `user_type`

```
TYPE user_type AS OBJECT (
  id                NUMBER,
  name              VARCHAR2(20),
  lastname          VARCHAR2(25),
  email             VARCHAR2(25),
  password          VARCHAR2(20),
  profile_pic       ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE,
  profile_pic_sig   ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature
)
```

and then I created the table `USERR` based on that type.
Inserting data works as expected

```
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO USERR
   VALUES (10,'user','username','somevalidemail','password', ORDSYS.ORDImage.init('FILE', 'C:\work','tess.jpg'),ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature.init());
 COMMIT;
END;
/
```

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Now the problem comes when I try to generate the signature of the image

```
DECLARE
 t_image     ORDSYS.ORDImage;
 image_sig   ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature;
BEGIN
 SELECT Profile_PIC, Profile_PIC_SIG INTO t_image, image_sig 
  FROM USERR
  WHERE ID = 10 FOR UPDATE;
 image_sig.generateSignature(t_image);
 UPDATE USERR SET Profile_PIC_SIG = image_sig 
  WHERE ID =10;
END;
/

ERROR
ORA-22285: répertoire ou fichier inexistant pour l'opération FILEOPEN
ORA-06512: à "ORDSYS.ORDIMG_PKG", ligne 1074
ORA-06512: à "ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE", ligne 173
ORA-06512: à "ORDSYS.ORDIMAGESIGNATURE", ligne 85
ORA-06512: à ligne 8
```

I've been wasting a lot of time with this problem and I can't find any solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDSYS.ORDImage.init('FILE', 'FILE_DIR','tess.jpg')
```

You should only specify the oracle directory name that you created reference for your actual folder path.

Comment: thanks for  the quick relpy! the same error is occurring

Comment: You deleted your previous entry?

Comment: after making a new directory and changing the path to FILE_DIR, it works.. i don't know why or how didn't this work before, even when using FILE_DIR in the constructor... thank you Maheswaran Ravisankar for your time !